# Is this function differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x + xe^{\frac{1}{x}} & x < 0\\ 
0 & x = 0\\ 
\frac{2-2\cos x}{\sin x} & 0 < x
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I want to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

But from the left, namely $f'_-(x)$ I get:

$$f'_-(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} 1 + e^{\frac{1}{x}} + x*-\frac{1}{x^2} 
e^{\frac{1}{x}} =  1 + 0 + \lim_{x \to 0^-} -\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$$

So I get $f'_-(0) \neq f'(0) = 0$, so there is a problem.

Comment: You erroneously differentiated $\mathrm e^{\tfrac1x}$.

Comment: when you differentiate e^1/x you get $$ e^{\frac{1}{x}}\times{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: Yea it was a typing mistake

Comment: Your post has the equation $f'(0)=0$ and your comment to the answer of @MichaelHardy has the same assertion. But you give no reason why $f'(0)=0$. Can you explain how you got that?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think $f'(0)=0?$ Nowhere did you prove this. Your claim that $f_-'(0)=1$ is correct. So if you show $f_+'(0)=1$ you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\text{“}x<0\text{''}$ in two of the parts of your definition of $f.$ I will assume only the first is correct.
\begin{align}
f'_-(0) & = \lim_{h\,\uparrow\,0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)} h  \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{n\,\uparrow\,0} \frac{h+he^{1/h}} h \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{h\,\uparrow\,0} \big( 1 + e^{1/h} \big) = 1.
\end{align}
As $h\,\uparrow\,0,$ we have $1/h\to-\infty,$ so $e^{1/h} \to 0.$

Comment: The problem is that you also get $1$, but its not equal to $0$, thats the problem, so it cant be differentiable at $0$ and i think it should be.

Comment: @Alon : Why do you think that?